# VoIP шлюз AP 100b не коннектится по SIP (SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required)

Tags: sip, voip

В трубке 2 секунды гудок, потом два сигнала, сброс линии и снова гудок. И так постоянно.

debug voip sip выдает следующее (при попытке поднять трубку)

```
 Sending SIP PDU to ( ip.b24-7680-1480537941.bitrixphone.com:5060 ) from 5060
REGISTER sip:ip.b24-7680-1480537941.bitrixphone.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.77:5060;branch=z9hG4bK8e00912da431
From: <sip:100@ip.b24-7680-1480537941.bitrixphone.com>;tag=8e00912da4
To: sip:100@ip.b24-7680-1480537941.bitrixphone.com
Call-ID: 8e0e0000-d792-91d0-802d-0002a4093eac@192.168.1.77
CSeq: 31 REGISTER
Date: Thu, 01 Jan 2011 01:04:49 GMT
User-Agent: AddPac SIP Gateway
Contact: <sip:100@192.168.1.77>;expires=60
Expires: 60
Content-Length: 0
Max-Forwards: 70



        Received SIP PDU from ( 95.213.198.99:5060 )
SIP/2.0 407 Proxy Authentication Required
v: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.1.77:5060;rport=3600;received=95.179.127.238;branch=z9hG4bK8e00912da431
i: 8e0e0000-d792-91d0-802d-0002a4093eac@192.168.1.77
f: <sip:100@ip.b24-7680-1480537941.bitrixphone.com>;tag=8e00912da4
t: <sip:100@ip.b24-7680-1480537941.bitrixphone.com>;tag=z9hG4bK8e00912da431
CSeq: 31 REGISTER
Proxy-Authenticate: Digest  realm="voximplant.com",nonce="0d3da6454056cec1",opaque="6f07daf95bdae2b7",algorithm=md5
l:  0
```

Второй день мучаюсь, подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Протокол реализован вручную или используется какой-то готовый SIP-клиент (какой)?

Comment: Программные SIP вы имеете ввиду? Не установлены. Аппарат AP100B, DECT телефон подключенный к нему и регистрационные данные, предоставленные поставщиком IP телефонии..

Comment: Сейчас попробовал через программный SIP клиент - тоже не коннектится. И с другой службой (Zadarma) те же грабли. Уж не в роутере в моем дело? Может порт закрыт или еще то?

Comment: @ЕвгенийТоршин ну так проверьте открыт ли порт во внешку на вашем маршрутизаторе (онлайн сервисов полно для этих целей) и верно ли написано правило проброса портов для вашего сервиса в нём же.

Comment: Сервисы показывают что порт 5060 закрыт. С пробросом портов не могу разобраться.. Для разных поставщиков IP телефонии разные правила?

Comment: Хотя через софтофон к Zadarma подключился успешно. Через шлюз с теми же настройками - не выходит. Вряд ли дело в закрытых портах..

Comment: Приведённый вами лог относится к процессу регистрации устройства - для приема входящих звонков. Для отладки проблем с исходящими звонками ищите в логах и дампах запрос INVITE. Ошибка 407 - даже не ошибка, а предложение другой стороны перепослать запрос с данными аутентификации. Если она приходит раз за разом, то проблема может быть в неправильных данных аутентификации. Устройство общается со шлюзом через NAT файрвол - если в нем есть функция SIP ALG, то попробуйте ее отключить. Ну и соберите более полный лог, где бы была видна вся транзакция целиком: запрос INVITE, 407, ACK, повтор, ответ.

Comment: Пример нормального call flow приведён https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3665 в районе 16-й страницы с комментариями. Сравните своё, может, появятся мысли.